# What happens to the other requests if one of them fails in Laravel Http pool request?

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to make a pool of requests to external partners, but their api endpoints are unstable so sometimes it happens that connection fails.

So I create this connections pool:

```
try{
    $response = Http::pool(function($pool) use($apiOrders){
        foreach($apiOrders as $order){  
            $order->supplierClass::pool($pool->as($order->supplierLabel))->createOrder($order->data);
        }
    });
}
catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e){
    $error = true;
    $response = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
}
catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e){
    $error = true;
    $response = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

what happens to other pool connections when, for example, the first connection fails?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I never use `foreach` inside `Http::pool`, but here's what I have used some time ago. Using this code for an example:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
$responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
    $pool->as('check_jpg')->head('http://localhost/my_photo.jpg'),
    $pool->as('check_jpeg')->head('http://localhost/my_photo.jpeg'),
    $pool->as('check_png')->head('http://localhost/my_photo.png'),
]);
```

I'm trying to check wether the 3 files exists in the url. The requests itself is being sent at the same time, as stated [in the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#concurrent-requests):

> ... several requests to be dispatched at the same time instead of issuing the requests sequentially...

Meaning that each request is independent and not affecting each other.

Then I'm able to do anything with the response from each request:

```php
if ( $responses['check_jpg']->successful() )  { /* do something... */ }
if ( $responses['check_jpeg']->successful() )  { /* do something... */ }
if ( $responses['check_png']->successful() )  { /* do something... */ }
```

I hope it helps.